# Laravel 5.3 “group by count” query issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Please I am trying to run a query that looks like this in raw sql

```
SELECT `qnty`, COUNT(*) FROM cartlist GROUP BY `pro_id`,`cart_id`,`price`
```

in laravel.

I have tried this

```
$count = DB::table('cartlist')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as qnty'))
                 ->where('pro_id', '$tt->pro_id')
                 ->where('cart_id', '$cart_id')
                 ->groupBy('pro_id','price')
                 ->get();
```

But it gives the following error

Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int

Comment: Why are there single quotes around `$cart_id` and `$tt->pro_id`?

Comment: $count = DB::table('cartlist')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as qnty'))
                     ->where('pro_id', $tt->pro_id)
      ->where('cart_id', $cart_id)
                     ->groupBy('pro_id','price')
                     ->get();

Comment: but still get that error

Comment: Your raw sql query and laravel query are really different. According to your raw SQL query, you're grouping by `pro_id`,`cart_id`,`price` and according to your laravel query you're only grouping by 'pro_id' and using the other three as where condition. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = DB::table('cartlist') ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as qnty')) 
                               ->where('pro_id', '$tt->pro_id') 
                               ->where('cart_id', '$cart_id') 
                               ->groupBy('pro_id','price','cart_id') ->get();
```